# foreign keys between databases, duplicating table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have two tables (some so-called dictionaries, only about ~50 entries I presume) that I want to be "shared" between two databases on the same MS sql express instance. Since I cannot make foreign keys cross-database, nor use foreign keys with a view, I've decided to duplicate the data in tables - however, I have no idea how to ;) What would be the best way to keep them in sync? Would it be best (and possible to do) with triggers (i.e. one master table, that I would modify, and the second table would have the changes applied), or do I have to do it on application-levell?

Comment: Triggers would work and probably make the most sense if it wont be a lot of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What thinkdevcode said in a comment (can't accept a comment now, can I): Triggers would work and probably make the most sense if it wont be a lot of data. –

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call a table on a separate database within the same server.

The addressing to the table from the other database would be `databasename.schema.tablename`.

You can even do this across servers if you have [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) setup - the naming scheme would then be `servername.databasename.schema.tablename`.

Comment: Yes, but I still would have to use constraints instead of foreign key relationships?

Comment: @trakos - foreign key **constraints** are not supported between servers/databases, as far as I know. You may be able to fake it using views.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQL Server replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) - but I'm not sure if it's in SQL Express.